# Select part of a string up to a certian character in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of part numbers in a table.

I would like to return everything to the left of the peroid character in postgresql.

My SQL is:

```
SELECT item.item_number 
FROM public.item;
```

it returns the following

```
item_number
340-1018-000.AAA
340-9922-000.AAB
9400-2007.006
```

desired

```
item_number
340-1018-000
340-9922-000
9400-2007
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with   [split_part](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html), for getting part before first occurrence of  period character:

```
SELECT split_part(item.item_number, '.', 1) as item_number FROM public.item;
```